# How Can I Query Pivoted Data?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table that has key value pairs plus the item it relates to.
e.g.

| CAR_NAME | PART_TYPE | PART_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VW | Tyre | Michelin 4WD |
| VW | Roof | Sun |
| Ford | Tyre | Michelin Sport |
| Ford | Roof | Glass |
| Audi | Tyre | Bridgestone |
| Audi | Roof | Soft |
| Mazda | Roof | Sun |

In reality there are about 60 different part types.

I want to get a list of car names where the tyre is not a Michelin.

```
select * from cars
where 
part_type = 'Tyre'
and part_name not like 'Michelin%'
```

This outputs Audi, however, I still want to include Mazda even though the tyre name is not specified.

It seems like a pivot would help but I don't fully understand the pivot syntax and then how to do the where clause after.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT car_name, part_type, part_name
  FROM cars 
)
PIVOT 
(
  LISTAGG(part_name ,',') 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY part_type) 
  FOR part_type IN (select distinct part_type from cars)
)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c89dc/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want something more like `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc.  `LISTAGG` can be used in a similar way, but isn't really necessary.  So this also solves the basic problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT car_name
  FROM cars
 WHERE car_name NOT IN (
            SELECT car_name FROM cars
             WHERE part_type = 'Tyre'
              AND part_name LIKE 'Michelin%'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

No pivot table is needed, a simple "OR" Operator will suffice here.
Make sure you separate the two conditions using parentheses. Parentheses are your friends when it comes to WHERE clauses and "AND/OR" Operators.

Try this:

```
select * from cars
where 
(part_type = 'Tyre'
and part_name not like 'Michelin%')
OR
(car_name = 'Mazda')
```

Comment: Whilst this answers the simple example in the question, it doesn't scale to a large data set e.g. all the car names in the world.